# calculate the sum of all square numbers between 1 and 100 in java

Tags: java

```
public class SumSquares {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num = 1;
    int square;
    int sum = 0;
    while(num <= 100){
        square = (num * num);
        sum = sum + square;
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

this is how i tried, in this the output is 338350, but this isn't what i want

this is what i want ==>
(1+4+9+16+25+36+49+64+81)= 285

*the output of the java program should be* **285**

Comment: Then you should probably check if `square <= 100`.

Comment: `while(num*num <= 100)` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stopping condition is wrong, since you are adding the squares from 1*1 to 100*100. You want to add squares from 1*1 to 9*9.

It should be:

```
while (num < 10) {
    square = (num * num);
    sum = sum + square;
    num++;
}
```

or

```
while (num * num < 100) {
    square = (num * num);
    sum = sum + square;
    num++;
}
```

Comment: Or rather `while(num <= Math.sqrt(100)) {...}`

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino That will work too, though it should be `<` based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Java 9` streams you could do as follows:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .map(v -> v * v)
            .takeWhile(v -> v < 100)
            .sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives :

```
        int num = 1;
        int square =0;
        int sum = 0;
        while(true){
            square = (num * num);
            if(square >=100) {break;}
            sum = sum + square;
            num++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

        //using java 8 Stream
        int sumUsingStream =  IntStream.range(1, 100)
                .filter((v)-> (v*v) < 100 )
                .map(v -> v * v)
                .sum();

        System.out.println(sumUsingStream);
```